# All movement jitters - caused by windows?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash

I'm using FlashDevelop 5.0.2.2 and also tried to compile on Flash Builder 4.6 ....

So, i have this game i'm building and i have noticed that every movement I made with code - it jitters. I tried with "release", tried different flash players - nothing, same thing. Also, implemented fixed frame rate, used elapsed time in other example - it's same for all tries - the movement jitters!

So, i went back,from mine old games, which are published and i know they run good - i compiled one of them - and now that games - jitters too.

I was wondering what is happening?

I'm using Windows 10 x64bit, with all the latest updates installed... also, the AIR SDK is the latest, so i don't know what i'm missing? Maybe some folder needs deleting or setting, i don't - tried many things, nothing helps.

help, please?

Comment: Please be more specific.  What exactly "jitters',  can you show a screen capture?   Post the least amount of code needed to reproduce the issue.  I've made lots of swf''s on Win 10 64-bit with no such issue - it's very unlikely it's the OS.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis - I'll try and upload a sample of swf... but, as I said - an old game of mine from 3-4 years, that was published online(paid and all) - and was working fine, now with this system I have, when I compile, the movement of the character(or anything) is not smooth, but it jaggs, jitters, idk ... if its not win, maybe flex sdk, idk ...

Comment: Consider running compilation via older FD distributive but with same SDK, to narrow the issue down to FD default compiler settings that could change with 5.0.